# Best way to travel from Vienna to Salzburg to Munich to Venice and back to Vienna, by car or train?

Tags: trains, transportation, germany, italy, austria

I've planned a trip to go from Vienna to Salzburg to Munich to Venice. So I'm basically going through 3 countries. What I don't know is how do I go there. Do I purchase train tickets or just rent a car? I'm going with 4 people so in total there are 5 including me.
I want to just go there and enjoy so I don't know if I should rent a car because I do not want to get tired and exhaust everyone in my family. Kindly guide me as to whether use the train or a car as a mean of transportation.

Comment: Welcome to the site! We tend to get a bit upset with subjective questions like 'what's the best' as it differs so much for everyone.  What is your goal? Are you comfortable driving? Are you trying to reduce stress, expenses or something else? I'd highly recommend editing your question to be more objective, or it's likely to get close votes :/

Answer (score 2):

If you rent a car, you will probably need a minivan. For one week you will have to foresee a budget of at least 1200 EUR (rental, fuel, toll, parking for one week) and 2000 EUR for two weeks. The roads are good and driving there is easy.

But for the same budget (and probably even less) you can also go by train. If you  want to visit the cities, you won't need a car. The train brings you from city center to city center. On the specified legs you have direct trains. Fro Venice to Vienna, you can even travel over night. So you will win one whole day on you trip.

Hence, take the train. It is more comfortable and a bit cheaper. And it is fun in a group of five.

To prepare your trip, have a look a the [trains tag](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trains) of this site. You will find answers to questions that you may have. And have a look at [The Man in Seat Sixty-One](http://www.seat61.com/).

Comment: http://www.interrail.eu/ is the right place to start looking, for a pan-European trip.

Comment: I would not recommend an Interrail ass for this particular trip. Buying single tickets will be cheaper here.

Comment: mmh I guess it depends how flexible the trip is and how long they want to spend in each country. But yeah this is definitely worth comparing the options.

Comment: Thank you very much for you response. I recently heard that if you travel by car you can stop at the small, cheap motels which are quiet good and are worth the experience. So should I book a hotel from now or just go there and live in motels. Who do you suggest?

Comment: What is so good about staying in the motels as opposed to staying in your intended destination? Also, just in addition to Marcel's answer, you can also book night train for longer distance like Munich to Venice.